# Whats size concrete aggregate

Tags: floor, cement

Not sure on what size stone/gravel i should use, 10 mm or 20 mm in my cement mix
1 cement + 2 sharp sand + 3 gravel (10mm or 20mm) ?

I need to fill 4 gully's in an internal concrete floor, each about 4m length x 0.08m width x 0.18m depth

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a narrow channel, I'd use 10mm aggregate.

You could even go to 4 parts gravel in the mix - a typical "go to" mix ratio for concrete is 1:2:4

Comment: Is the reason for going 10mm just because of the size of opening? It quite deep though 18cm.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the depth. The smaller aggregate will be easier to work into the narrow width.